# How to check a signature with Terminal on Mac

Tags: macos, command-line, gnupg, macos-highsierra

I'm trying to verify the signatures of sha256sums.gpg and sha256sums with the following commands in terminal (using mac)

```
$ gpg --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
```

Instead, I get this answer...! :-(

```
unknown:~ username$ gpg --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
-bash: gpg: command not found
unknown:~ username$
```

What did I do wrong...?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the `gpg` command is not found. Do you have GnuPG installed?

I would recommend you install the [GPGTools Suite](https://gpgtools.org).

It provides the `gpg` command, but also GPG integration for Apple Mail and related graphical utilities. This may be more than you need or want.

---

You could also install GnuPG with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
$ brew install gnupg
```

Homebrew is a package manager similar to for example `yum` or `apt` in different Linux distributions, but for macOS. You may prefer this if you are already using Homebrew or are planning to use it to install more (command line) tools in the future.

---

If you just want to verify the checksum (not the signature), you can use

`shasum -a 256 <filename>`

without installing anything.

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
$ brew install gnupg
```

then

```bsh
$ gpg --verify key file
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have `shasum` available on a Mac already. If you download a 256 sum, you can do

```
shasum -a 256 filetoverify.tgz > 256.txt
```

then compare this to your downloaded sum file

```
diff 256.txt downloaded256sumfile
```

You might see a complaint about

```
\ No newline at end of file
```